# Mongo UpdateMany command in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
diseaseModel.updateMany({matched: current_matched, "$text":{"$search" : `\"${desc}\"`}}, {$inc: {matched: 1}})
```

I'm trying to find and update my documents that have the field "matched" that matches a variable, and text in the document that matches another variable but this doesn't work, what is the problem with this command?

Answer (score 1):

Following way is working:

```
diseaseModel.updateMany({ matched: current_matched , "$text":{"$search" : `${desc}`  }}, {$inc: {matched: 1}})
```